# Расширить область видимости декоратора

Tags: python-2.7, декоратор

Всем привет!

Есть декоратор:

```
def clock(str):
    def wrap(function):
        def called(*args, **kwargs):
            logging.info(s, function, args, kwargs)
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return called
    return wrap
```

который замеряет время выполнения функции. Сделан для логгирования, работает нормально. Иногда однако нужно записывать еще номер итерации (попытки) исполнения функции.

Функция

```
@clock('fetching_data')
def fetch_data():
   # ....
```

которая считывает данные с сервера

```
iteration = 1
for proxy in proxies:
   fetch_data()
   logging.info(iteration)
   iteration += 1
```

вызывается в цикле. Логгирование происходит внутри функции, так как мне нужно записывать в лог-файл номер итерации, чтобы знать с какого раза удалось считать данные

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ переложить функционал записи номера попытки внутрь декоратора?

Или это вообще невозможно?